# Adding X-Content-Type-Options to web.config causes page source to be returned?

Tags: .net, http-headers, web-config, content-type, x-content-type-options

My apologies if this is a basic question, but here goes:

I'm seeing a confusing issue when setting *HTTP headers* in my *.NET Core* website's *web.config*

In the "*customHeaders*" element, I've added the "*X-Content-Type-Options*" header with value "*nosniff*".

[image: Custom headers]

**Before this is added the server response shows the "Content-Type" header**
[image: Chrome DevTools - response headers before setting X-Content-Type-Options]

**However, once the "*X-Content-Type*" Header is set, no "Content-type" header is returned**
[image: Chrome DevTools - response headers after setting X-Content-Type-Options]

**Additionally, the site now displays the *page source* rather than the rendered page/content:**
[image: Page source returned instead of rendered content]

**Reading about this I see that setting the "X-Content-Type-Options" header should simply**

- Indicate the MIME types in the "Content-Type" headers should be followed and not changed
- Prevent MIME type sniffing

The recommendation on several resources (MDN, OWASP) states both headers should be used together and are expected to be set to pass "site security testing".

**Questions**

- Could the "page source" response be due to application code at the server stripping or changing the MIME type from "text/html" in the "Content-Type" header?
- Why would setting the "X-Content-Type-Options" cause the server to do this?

**What's been tried**

- Load site without "X-Content-Type-Options" header, inspect in Chrome DevTools
- Add the "X-Content-Type-Options" header to the "web.config" file, reload the site and compare headers in response

**Expectation**

- Setting both headers renders page as normal with MIME type sniffing disabled

**Sources:**

- [MDN: X-Content-Type-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)
- [OWASP: X-Content-Type-Options](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Headers_Cheat_Sheet.html#x-content-type-options)

Any advice on this would be appreciated! Thanks.